# I'm trying to make a rock paper scissors game in python, but am getting an unindent does not match any outer indent lever error

Tags: python, error-handling

Here's the code. The error is on the `input("Do you want to continue?")` line.

```py
import random

def play():
    gameOver = False
    while not gameOver: 
        imput = input("rock, paper, or scissors?")
        j = 0
        if (imput == "rock"):
            j = 1
        elif(imput == "paper"):
            j = 2
        else:
            j = 3

        robot = random.randint(1,3) 

        if j == robot:
            print("you got the same thing")
        elif j == 1:
            if robot == 2:
                print("Rock vs Paper, you lose")
            else:
                print("Rock vs Scissors, you win!")
        elif j == 2:
            if robot == 1:
                print("paper vs rock, you win!")
            else:
                print("paper vs scissors, you lose")

        else:
            if robot == 1:
                print("Scissors vs Rock, you lose")
            else:
                print("Scissors vs paper, you win!")
        
        decision = input("Do you want to continue?")
        if decision == "yes":
            gameOver == True

play()
```

Comment: Ah, a classic easy fix: try unindenting everything and reindenting them. If you have a decent text editor, this should be easy.

Comment: Do you have tabs vs spaces somewhere?

Comment: Can't reproduce the error.  (You do have a bug at `gameOver = True` though!)

Comment: Pasting this into an interpreter works fine.  Have you checked to see if there are tabs/spaces issues on your local machine, or if you are referring to an old `.pyc` file somehow (moved directory?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get parse error when I run this code you posted. My guess is tabs vs. spaces. Change the settings of your editor to always use 4 spaces when you press the tab key, and find-and-replace any existing tab characters to be replaced by 4 spaces.

Comment: I would also add that there are a lot of errors in your code. Not syntax errors, but just program errors. For instance, when I enter " " for my option, it tells me, "You got the same thing". It is really buggy.

Comment: Let's let the OP go one step at a time! :-)

Comment: Ok, that seems reasonable.